# set a c++ class nil in xcode ".mm" file.

Tags: c++, xcode4, box2d

In somebody's project I found a error. I know it is wrong. But it works well.

in .mm file do like this

```
- (void) DestroySelfBody{
    [self unschedule:@selector(DestroySelfBody)];
    if (m_body) {
        m_body->GetWorld()->DestroyBody(m_body);
        m_body = nil;
    }
}
```

m_body is define by (b2Body is a c++ class):

```
b2Body * m_body;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nullptr` for C++ types: `m_body = nullptr;`.

Comment: do you mean : m_body = NULL; nullptr is not defineded.

Comment: Now I want to know why set m_body=nil don't show error and run well.

Comment: @zszen `nullptr` is C++11 (this feature is available in clang for some time). if you must use an older version of C++, `NULL` would be a fine substitute. there is some underlying equivalence - in fact, `nil` and `Nil` are defined to `nullptr` in more recent system headers. despite this underlying equivalence, people still associate `nil` with objc objects, and not C++ types.